# MongoDB Shell How can I average or $min/$max a sum of strings

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I've been trying to get my head around aggregation for a while now and I can't seem to work out how to find the average, min or max, of a sum of strings.

```
    db.mycollectionname.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$Monitor"},
        {$group: {_id: "$Monitor.Mon Type",
        "Total": {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

I know it's not much, but this is how far I managed to get, it pumps out this;

```
{ "_id" : "RM", "Total" : 21 }
{ "_id" : "PT", "Total" : 43 }
{ "_id" : "IM", "Total" : 24 }
{ "_id" : "IO", "Total" : 72 }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the min/max of these sum results and an average of all the results.
Any help or advice is appreciated, can't seem to find anything that helps me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this stage as last stage :

```
{$group :{_id:'', minimum :{$min: '$Total'}, maximum :{$max: '$Total'}, Total :{$sum : '$Total'}, average :{$avg : '$Total'}}}
```

So your query :

```
db.mycollectionname.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$Monitor" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Monitor.Mon Type",
            "Total": { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '', minimum: { $min: '$Total' }, maximum: { $max: '$Total' },
            Total: { $sum: '$Total' }, average: { $avg: '$Total' }
        }
    }
])
```

So when you do `_id: ''` or `_id: null`, a group stage would iterate through all the documents at that point. After adding final `$group` stage result should be :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "",
    "minimum" : 21.0,
    "maximum" : 72.0,
    "Total" : 160.0,
    "average" : 40.0
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I run the query, I get the error message, 'The field 'Total' must be an accumulator object', am I missing anything in the query or is it an issue related to my data? I used the solution you posted in response as said query.

Comment: Can you give me your query here

Comment: ` db.mycollectionname.aggregate([{$unwind: "$Monitor"}, {$group: {_id: "$Monitor.Mon Type", "Total": {sum: 1}}}, {$match: {Total:"Total"}}, {$group: {_id: '', minimum: {$min: "$Total"}, maximum: {$max: "$Total"}, Total: {$sum: "$Total"}, average: {$avg: "$Total"}}}]) `

Comment: What is that $match between two $groups doing there? After first group Total will be a number you’re filtering documents in match stage with Total = ‘Total’ which leaves no documents for second group stage

Comment: oop sorry that was me trying to sort it, here's the query that returns the error; db.Contracts.aggregate([{$unwind: "$Monitor"}, {$group: {_id: "$Monitor.Mon Type", "Total": {sum: 1}}}, {$group: {_id: '', minimum: {$min: "$Total"}, maximum: {$max: "$Total"}, Total: {$sum: "$Total"}, average: {$avg: "$Total"}}}])

Comment: This should not give you an error it’s working for me what is your mongoDB version?

Comment: I'm using mongodb 4.0.14 for shell and 4.0.14 for my cluster on Atlas

Comment: Then this should work can you remove second group stage and see first group stage is returning results as like what you’ve given in question also check minimum maximum and total avg one by one to see where it’s failing

Comment: I've tried that and even the initial query I posted returns that error now, going to try my laptop and see if it is just my pc playing up

Comment: @Sppicy : ok issue is in first group stage it has to be $sum what you’ve is just sum change it everything will work